# Port forwarding to a VirtualBox image fails after suspend-resume

Tags: networking, port, virtualbox, nat, forwarding

We use vagrant to setup a VirtualBox image with Ubuntu Linux. It has private network enabled, and a number of ports are forwarded - here are some snippets from our Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306  #mysql
...
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8098, host: 8098  #riak http
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8087, host: 8087  #riak pb
```

This works allright when the VM is started.

But after the host machine has been suspended for a while (more than a brief period) and resumes, then the port forwarding does not work any more.

Everything responds fine on the allocated private network address, `192.168.33.10`, but not on `localhost` where the attempt just hangs.

Any ideas for a solution?

Specs:

```
Host OS: Mac OS X, version 10.9 "Mavericks"  
Guest OS: Ubuntu 12.04, precise64 (standard box from vagrantup.com)
Vagrant 1.4.0  
VirtualBox version: VirtualBox 4.3.4 r91027  

Virtual Box > Machine Settings > Network
  Adapter 1: 
    Attached to: NAT
    Cable Connected : True
    Port Forwarding:
      TCP, HostIP=,          HostPort=3306, GuestIP=, GuestPort=3306
      TCP, HostIP=,          HostPort=8098, GuestIP=, GuestPort=8098
      TCP, HostIP=,          HostPort=8087, GuestIP=, GuestPort=8087
      TCP, HostIP=127.0.0.1, HostPort=2222, GuestIP=, GuestPort=22
```

I found a similar question, but can not seem to use the same answer: [VirtualBox port forwarding not working with NAT adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580525/virtualbox-port-forwarding-not-working-with-nat-adapter)

Comment: Somehow I think the value of `GUESTIP` should have something