# docker Error getting IP address: ssh command error exit status 255

Tags: linux, windows, boot2docker

I am using the Oracle VM VurtualBox 5.1.18 version

Windows 10 version 64bit, and "Docker Quick Start Terminal"

I installed the docker terminal and tried to run it. I got this message.

[image]

So I ran it again and I get this message.

[image]

so, When I tried "$docker-machine ls" command, the following message was printed.

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running                 Unknown   ssh command error:
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

To solve the problem, I tried the following command.

```
$ Docker-machine rm default
$ Docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Nevertheless, the same phenomenon repeats itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed ProxyCap?

thanks to [@alastairtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44109624/2227031), he reminded me that ProxyCap will make the VirtualBox error when setting up port forwarding. If you check the VirtualBox log, log file path: `C:\Users\demo\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBox.log`

You can find the error message `supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\windows\system32\pcapwsp.dll': rcNt=0xc0000190`

`pcapwsp.dll` is part of ProxyCap, after uninstalling ProxyCap, everything is fine